# android dictionary using trie

Tags: android, dictionary

i want to build a android dictionary app using trie. so m i new to this platform, how could i possibly start things... plz anyone can help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android developer site is a great place to start from: http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html

After you read the basics, start with a tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=tutorial

If you have any specific question after that, when you start implementing your application, you are welcome to ask.